# background color change of a tooltip in google maps

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-visualization

I am using google chart. now on hovering countries i am showing a tooltip which is fetching data from backend and showing. Now the background color of that tooltip I want to change. By default it is white

here is code

```
  activity_chartdata = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  activity_chartdata.addColumn('string', 'Country');
  activity_chartdata.addColumn('number', 'Activity');
  activity_chartdata.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip'}); //
  activity_chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('social_activity_map_chart_div'));

  var mapData = data['Payload'][0]['mapDataPoints'];

  jQuery.each(mapData, function (index, value) {
                activity_chartdata.addRow([{
                    v: value['shortCode'],
                    f: value['countryName']
                },parseFloat(value['activityCount']), "Activity:  " + reformatNumber(value['activityCount'])]);
   });
            var options = {
                colorAxis: {colors: colorArray},
                showZoomOut: "true",
                //backgroundColor: '#CBD0D1',
                datalessRegionColor: '#ffffff',
                defaultColor: '#ffffff',
                zoomOutLabel: 'Zoom Out',
                keepAspectRatio: true,
                height: finalHeight
            };
            activity_chart.draw(activity_chartdata, options);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the tooltips a style like this:

```
g>g>path[fill="#ffffff"] {
fill: #000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, look at the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_tooltip_content#customizing-html-content). You can find there some examples.

1. You have to specify `tooltip.isHtml: true` in the chart options
2. Mark an entire column, or a specific cell, in the data table with the html custom property. A datatable column with the tooltip role and HTML property would be:
   *`dataTable.addColumn({'type': 'string', 'role': 'tooltip', 'p': {'html': true}})`*

Answer (score 0):

Refer [this link](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_tooltip_content#tooltips-an-introduction)..

You can use custom tooltip.

[image]